# Trying to understand what this JS function does and what its parameters are, can someone explain?

Tags: javascript, closures, amd, commonjs

I'm reading through some code from a library I recently downloaded to do matrix math for WebGL. However, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what this function does. This comes from the glMatrix.js library.

```
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
  (global = global || self, factory(global.glMatrix = {}));
}(this, function (exports)
```

What is the factory parameter/function and where does exports come from? Can someone walk me step-by-step through what this function does?

EDIT: This is only the first part of the code which is why the opening bracket never closes.

Comment: This is initialization of a [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) style module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a design pattern called [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), it is a more advanced version of the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) design pattern. They both wrap your code, creating a new private scope. The main diferrence between the two is that `UMD` is more abstract and will also work in `node.js` and `amd` rather than just browsers.

The first and last line you are showing in your question are basically the `IIFE` part (minus the end since you have cropped it). You are invoking the `iife` and passing the `global` aka `window` object and the `factory` function which you can only see the `function (exports)` part in your code.

The following part checks if the environment you are using is node, amd or regular `JS`so that they will define the module in the each environmest requires i.e. `node` just needs you to set the `exports` object, `amd` needs you to use the `define` function and in vanilla `JS` you just add the object to the `window` or `global` object.

```
typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
(global = global || self, factory(global.glMatrix = {}));
```

In node and amd you don't need to name your export since you just need to require that file i.e. `const glMatrix = require("./common.js");`, but in JS you need to retrieve from the global object which is why it's only one that requires to be named i.e. `factory(global.glMatrix = {})`. That line adds the `glMatrix` property to the global object (originally as an empty object) and then passes it as a parameter to your `factory` function, which attaches all the functions, values and classes you should be able to access from outside the scope.

The implementation of the `UMD` pattern may vary from library to library. For example here is a way you could do it without passing any parameters to the `IIFE`

```js
(function() {
  var global = this;

  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
    (global = global || self, factory(global.foo = {}));

  function factory(exports) {
    exports.bar = function() {
      console.log("Hello World!");
    };
  }
})();

foo.bar();
```

In node you can just create a new file and export whatever you want. Node will then associate those exports with the file rather than a property (which is what happens in browser JS). So for example a file named `foo.js` with the following contents:

```
function bar() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
}

exports.bar = bar;
```

Can be accessed from another file like so:

```
const foo = require("foo.js");
foo.bar();
```

Or you could directly access the properties using [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const { bar } = require("foo.js");
bar();
```

Comment: So how does node and amd decide on the name for the module if it isn't required to input a name?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the factory parameter/function

It's the second argument to the function … the beginning of which is defined on the last line of the code you included. The rest of it you cut off.

> where does exports come from

When you call it. Here: `factory(global.glMatrix = {})`

Comment: True, but you might want to address the intent of the code or provide a reference that does so.  Granted that's not a simple thing to do because there are numerous official variants of the UMD pattern. However that's also why it's important because it's far from rare to encounter a broken, hand tweaked version that fails in certain environments.